# logout using express and passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using express.js and passport-jwt and I'm creating a middleware that checks user in every API call and then assigns to req a user. So then every time I log `req.user`, I get details about my user and that works fine. Then if I want to log this user out I used `req.logout()`, `req.logOut()`, `req.destroy()` and even I tried to assign `null` to `req.user` and it still logged in please I need help.

**passport config**

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
var passport = require('passport')
 const User = require('../schema/userSchema')


var opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = 'social';

exports.Strategy = new JwtStrategy(opts, async (jwt_payload, done) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: jwt_payload.id})
     if (!user) {
        return done({error:'error'}, false);
     }
     if (user) {
        return done(null, user);
     } else {
        return done({error:'error'}, false);
     }      

})

exports.auth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false })
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors')
var passport = require('passport')
var passportmethods = require('./methods/passport')
var postRoute = require('./router/posts')
var authRoute = require('./router/auth')
var friendRoute = require('./router/friend')
var verif = require('./router/user')

app.use('/uploads',express.static('../backend Social/uploads'))

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
passport.use(passportmethods.Strategy)

app.use('/auth',authRoute)
app.use('/post',passportmethods.auth,postRoute)
app.use('/friend',passportmethods.auth,friendRoute)
app.use('/user',passportmethods.auth,verif)


app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('server on !'))
```

**loggedin and logout**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const logout = require('express-passport-logout');
const User = require('../schema/userSchema')




router.get('/isloggedin', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.user) res.send(req.user)
    else res.send({ error: 'error' })
})

router.get('/logout',async (req, res, next) => {
    await User.updateOne({_id:req.user._id},{$set :{connected : false}}) 
    console.log(req.user._id)
    req.logOut()
    if(req.user)res.send(req.user._id)
    else res.send('logged out')
})
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you shouldn't implement logout from the server side. Let your clients handle the logout, because we don't store the token anywhere in the server. So, to logout from the client, you simply delete the token. Also, don't store your tokens in the database unless you must do it, and if you are to do it, then hash them like passwords. Storing tokens in the database is risky in case of security vulnerability in the database, the intruder will have all the powers to do whatsoever.

Comment: i wanna remove req.user how to remove it i want when to test it there is req.user it gets null

Comment: what version of passport are you using? but a way around it could be using `req.session.destroy()` and passing a callback to it clearing cookies then redirecting.  But still I don't use passport and I think it is a good idea to implement logout on client.

Comment: "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0"

Comment: i cant use req.session.destroy() because i m not using session and cookies howa can i implement them in my code ?

Comment: `router.get('/logout',async (req, res, next) => {
    await User.updateOne({_id:req.user._id},{$set :{connected : false}}) 
    console.log(req.user._id)
    req.session.destroy(function() {
       res.redirect('/'))
    if(req.user)res.send(req.user._id)
    else res.send('logged out')
})`

Answer (score 0):

First - you use endpoint as middleware. I would try without 'next'. Then - I would try with req.logout() not  req.logOut(). Also wrap your await call with try - catch block. Maybe there is problem with the Schema promise.